# A polite word for female facilities

Tags: vocabulary, word-comparison

What would be a good Latin word for "women", "ladies", "female(s)", or the like when I want to indicate the gender designation of a sauna or a toilet?
In English I would choose "ladies", or perhaps in a very informal setting "women".
I specifically want to avoid any offending or pejorative tones in the word, and I am not sure which Latin word would be the best choice.
*Femina*, *mulier*, and *domina* come to mind, but I am unsure about how their tones compare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the adjective *muliebris* would work.

In *On Architecture*, Vitruvius writes in book 5, chapter 10, 'On Baths', that care should be taken that the hot baths for men and for women be adjacent:

> *... uti caldaria **muliebria** et virilia coniuncta*

Comment: Thanks! I imagine Vitruvius was after a neutral tone, so this is good support for *mulier* and *muliebris*.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there's any doubt. *Domina* has a suggestion of class, the primary meaning of *femina* is 'female' (of whatever species), *puella* is age-restricted but *mulier* is a general word that can apply to all, with the advantage of the related adjective *muliebris* that Penelope has pointed out.